# Another (simpler) trouble with type variance

Tags: scala, types, parameters, generic-variance

I had a (looong) version of this problem posted yesterday here:
[Trouble with type variance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45741536/trouble-with-type-variance)

To cut the (really) long story short, this:

```
 class A[-P, T <: P]
```

does not compile (it complains, that "P occurs in covariant position in type  <: P of type T").
An answer to my earlier question suggested that the declaration is indeed invalid, because `A[Foo, Bar]` would be a subclass of `A[Nothing, Bar]`, but the latter is illegal (`Bar` isn't a subclass of `Nothing`).

I don't think that's reason enough. By that logic, something like this should be illegal too: `class B[+T <: String]` - `B[String]` should be a subclass of `B[Any]` but the latter is invalid.

**Moreover**, this:

```
class C[T, -P >: T]
```

Actually does compile. Isn't this essentially the same exact thing as `A` above?

Comment: `B[Any]` is invalid because `Any` is not a subtype of `String`, no?

Comment: @AlvaroCarrasco exactly! `A[Nothing, Bar]` would be invalid for the same reason.

Answer (score 1):

These are subtly different.

```
class Test[-P, T <: P]
```

says "let `P` be a type parameter that varies contravariantly and unboundedly, and let `T` be a subtype of `P`." That is, `T` is completely ignored when checking whether a type is valid for `P`. Only then is `T` constrained to be a subtype of `P`. This is illegal, for the reason you already know. You can start with `Test[Any, String]`, and because `P` is unboundedly contravariant, it can become `Test[Nothing, String]`, and suddenly you have `String <: Nothing`.

```
class tseT[T, -P :> T] // Code highlighters HATE him. Click to find out why.
```

says "let `T` be a type parameter that doesn't vary and is unbounded, and then let `P` be a contravariant type parameter that is lower-bounded by `T`." This is tiny bit different, because this time `P`'s variance is constrained by the lower bound `T`. `P` still varies contravariantly, but it cannot vary lower than `T`, or else it will violate `P >: T`. This is safe, because you can start with `tseT[String, Any]`, and then `P` can only vary down as long as it is still a supertype of `String`, so it is illegal for `P` to vary down to `Nothing`.

Note that type parameters are processed left-to-right. This is why the first example is declared invalid, instead of inferring the bound `P >: T`, because `T` is not declared yet when `P` is processed, and such a bound would be a forward-reference anyway.

Comment: I still don't get why first example is illegal, and the second one is not: sure, `Test[Nothing, String]` is invalid, but so is `tseT[String, Nothing]` ...

Comment: Correct. The thing is that with the first one, `P` can vary as much as likes, without regard for with `T` is. Therefore, `P` can vary into `Nothing`, no matter what `T` is, and break things. In the second, `P` can only vary *down to* `T`. You don't just constrain `P >: T`, you constrain the *variance* of `P` too, so it can't vary below `T`. The first one is therefore invalid, for it can always break, but the second one is valid, and the compiler just won't let you write the type `tseT[String, Nothing]`, while other instantiations work.